# How to add some information in the wordpress-mu footer?

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to add some information in the wordpress footer.
I make some modifications to the footer.php file in the theme I used now.
The Code is below:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains footer content and the closing of the
 * #main and #page div elements.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?>
    </div><!-- #main .wrapper -->
    <footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="site-info">
            <?php do_action( 'twentytwelve_credits' ); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentyeleven' ), 'WordPress'); ?></a>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
        <div><?php echo "test"; ?></div>
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The output I expect is the string "test" in the footer of my blog, but the actual result is that the string "test" isn't in the footer.
My wordpress version is 3.5.2 and I'm using wordpress-MU and buddypress as plugins.
Any help plz~~

Comment: There is error because you have used PHP comment as HTML.

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya： How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya: //add by me is not exist is the final code, I just want to present where I add the code?

Comment: Hi Charles0429.your code is perfactly working in my Twenty Twelve theme.i have just test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code inside site info div:

```
<div class="site-info"><!-- .site-info --></div>
```